# can't get to second activity after spots dialog "keep's on loading"

Tags: java, android

can't get to second activity after spots dialog "keep's on loading" on my main activity and can load for hours without error i use facebook acount kit i dont see the error out here is the main activity source code 
main activity java :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
Button btnContinue;
RelativeLayout rootLayout;

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference users;

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //bf4 set context view
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    printKeyHash();

    //Init Firebase
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users = db.getReference(Common.user_driver_tbl);

    //init view
    btnContinue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);

    rootLayout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);


    //Event
    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signInwithPhone();
        }
    });


    //auto login to facebook act kit for second time
    if (AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken() != null)
    {
        //create dialog
        final AlertDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(this);
        waitingDialog.show();
        waitingDialog.setMessage("Please waiting....");
        waitingDialog.setCancelable(false);

        AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Account account) {
                //copy from exiting user
                users.child(account.getId())//fixed
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                Common.currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DriverHome.class);
                                startActivity(homeIntent);

                                //Dismiss dialog
                                waitingDialog.dismiss();
                                finish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {

            }
        });
    }

}

private void signInwithPhone() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountKitActivity.class);
    AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
            new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(LoginType.PHONE,
                    AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);
    intent.putExtra(AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,configurationBuilder.build());
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        AccountKitLoginResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(AccountKitLoginResult.RESULT_KEY);
        if (result.getError() !=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+result.getError().getErrorType().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        else if (result.wasCancelled())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        else{
            if (result.getAccessToken() !=null)
            {
                //Show dialog
                final AlertDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(this);
                waitingDialog.show();
                waitingDialog.setMessage("Please waiting....");
                waitingDialog.setCancelable(false);

                //get current phone
                AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final Account account) {
                        final String userId = account.getId();

                        //check if exist on firebase
                        users.orderByKey().equalTo(account.getId())
                                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        if (!dataSnapshot.child(account.getId()).exists())//if not exits
                                        {
                                            //will we create new user login
                                            final User user = new User();
                                            user.setPhone(account.getPhoneNumber().toString());
                                            user.setName(account.getPhoneNumber().toString());
                                            user.setAvatarUrl("");
                                            user.setRates("0.0");

                                            //Register to Firebase
                                            users.child(account.getId())
                                                    .setValue(user)
                                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                                            //Login
                                                            users.child(account.getId())
                                                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                                            Common.currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                                                                            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DriverHome.class);
                                                                            startActivity(homeIntent);

                                                                            //Dismiss dialog
                                                                            waitingDialog.dismiss();
                                                                            finish();
                                                                        }

                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                                        }
                                                                    });

                                                        }
                                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else //if user existing ,login
                                        {
                                            users.child(account.getId())
                                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                            Common.currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                                                            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DriverHome.class);
                                                            startActivity(homeIntent);

                                                            //Dismiss dialog
                                                            waitingDialog.dismiss();
                                                            finish();
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                        }
                                                    });


                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+accountKitError.getErrorType().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

private void printKeyHash() {
    try{
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.rd.androidapp",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature:info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KEYHASH", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

if more is needed !!! or is there something lacking also i am still new in android programing so ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to uses dismiss the dialog in onCancel and onError method and print error for discretion.

Comment: I think your onDataChange is not getting called , put log n check

Comment: can you explaine more please i try to dismiss at oncancel and etc but crash insated talha shahid

Comment: amit ranjan i think i did that by dimissing at end or if you can tell more please about or how to use log n check

Comment: You have to loge the error in onCancel and in onError. It will log your error in console. e.g  Log.d("you tag", error.getMessage).